# JQuery removing added event

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to remove an attached event on an object, e.g `$("button").hover(function(){ // DO What ever});` now after some browser resize i need to remove this event, I have tried using `$("selector").on( hover,function(){ // DO What ever});` and removing it by using `$("selector").off(hover);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no event called hover, it is a utility method to register mouseenter and mouseleave handlers so try

```
$("selector").off('mouseenter  mouseleave ');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$("selector").unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
```

[JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhana36/mt4nz/)